# When is an infinite sequence of integers purely deterministic with no randomness involved?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random, random-walk

I see in literature very different descriptions of what is a *deterministic* system such as:

"*... a system in which no randomness is involved in the development of future states of the system*[...>>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system)"

I have this clear but rather broad question that might be answered by different opinions and view points. However, my question is really not targeting an intuitive or phiplosophical answer, and I beg you for view points with a strength of mathematical foundation:

May one explain based on a formal mathematical description, what needs to be exactly fulfilled in order to justify that *an infinite [sequence of positive integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sequence)* $\langle  x_i \rangle$, along its forward progression (that means vs. increasing $i$), is *purely deterministic* with no *randomness involved*?

$i \in \Bbb N$ and $x \in \Bbb N$.

---

*A posterior*

Following the first comments, let me carefully *conjecture* the following that might be correct and possibly helping to a rather concrete and qualified answer to the above question by the community:

1. *Any* such sequence (abovementioned) can be described in some way by some probability distribution that *involves randomness*. Here probability means the probability that certain integer occurs at a certain location $i$ of the sequence.
2. Taking such probability distribution into account, *any* such sequence can be described by either a linear or non-linear *master equation*, that can represent the stochastic model for that sequence.
3. This stochastic model of such sequence encapsulates substantial information about the *interaction* (association) of the elements $x_i$ of the sequence (along progression) as well as the *memory* ($x_{i-1},x_{i-2},x_{i-3},\dots$) that is required for predicting $x_{i+1},x_{i+2},x_{i+3},\dots$ (*determinism*)
4. If the *first, second and higher moments* and *their interactions* would allow, there might be a possibility to connect the *stochastic model* (that includes randomness) to a *deterministic model*.
5. While any such sequence can be described in some way by some probability distribution that involves randomness, not every such sequence must have a deterministic description and
6. dependent on the *moments* and the way they interact, it is not always possible to derive from the stochastic model a deterministic model.

Comment: Intuitively, it is deterministic if knowing what $x_n$ is means that you can tell me what $x_{n+1}$ will be.

Comment: *...my question is really not targeting an intuitive or phiplosophical answer...*

Comment: What exactly do you want from a "mathematical description"? To me, the above would be enough. To say something has no randomness means that probabilities are not involved, so there is no need to get bogged down in probabilistic formalism. If you really wanted to, I suppose you could define the sequence to be a markov chain where each transition probability is either $0$ or $1$, but this seems unnecessary.

Comment: what if you dont have yet found to the rule that brings you (in your specific example) from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stochastic" or "probabilistic" or "random" in this context means there is a probability distribution assigned to it.  The probability that the sequence has thus-and-such behavior is this number.

"Deterministic" simply means that it does not.

The word "random", like the word "infinity" actually has a variety of different uses in mathematics, the relationship between which is often not defined in a logically rigorous way.  For example, Kolmogorov-Chaitin randomness is a different thing from what I write about above.

Comment: Do you mean, if I correctly understand, that such sequence that is *assigned deterministic* must not possess a *probability distribution*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "assigned deterministic".  If we say that the probability is $1/4$ that a sequence of numbers is $0,0$ and $1/4$ that it is $0,1$, and $1/4$ that it is $1,0$ and $1/4$ that it is $1,1$, then that's a random sequence of two digits.  The sequence $0,1$, on the other hand is a deterministic sequence.

Comment: see above extension please